# Best Way To Process Data in SQL Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

Well, I stepped in it now. I'm converting a program from Access vba to C# so I can run it independently (that's another story...) The program reads an Excel file and then validates each row and column to be sure the data is valid (numeric, etc) and then looks up various data fields to create a transaction table on SQL Server. The transaction table is never re-validated, so it must be correct on the first try.

I'm used to procedural languages (though I have a passable knowledge of T-SQL), but now (VS2010) it appears I need to use either "LINQ to SQL" or "Entity Data Model" to get the data out of SQL Server (2005). Historically, I've used DAO or ADO recordsets. I need to retrieve multiple columns at a time, though by and large, I won't be updating the tables. I can make the updates using SQL Server stored procedures (and presumably ADO?)

Although I've begun work using Windows Forms, I'm likely to shift it over to a console app before I finish.

What do you guys recommend? My book (C# 4.0 Griffiths, Adams and Liberty) has been talking about Entity Data Model mostly. But since I'm using SQL Server (2005) exclusively, isn't "Linq to SQL" more appropriate? Any references to help me get started? Here's an example "method" (in vba...) that I'm using now that's pretty standalone that I'm using for my first attempt:

```
Function ValidateOverride(LaborRateID As Variant) As Long
If IsNull(LaborRateID) = True Or IsNumeric(LaborRateID) = False Then
    ValidateOverride = 0
    Exit Function
End If

Dim rstOverrideLaborRates As DAO.Recordset2
Set rstOverrideLaborRates = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblStaffAugLaborRates WHERE ID=" & LaborRateID, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges + dbFailOnError)
If rstOverrideLaborRates.EOF Then
    HandleMessages "Row Rejected -- Invalid Override Labor Rate"
    ValidateOverride = 0
Else
    ValidateOverride = LaborRateID
    If (dtCurrentWorkDate < rstOverrideLaborRates!EffectiveDate) Or (dtCurrentWorkDate > rstOverrideLaborRates!ExpirationDate) Then
        HandleMessages "Row Rejected -- Override Labor Rate is not within its valid dates"
        ValidateOverride = 0
    End If
    If rstOverrideLaborRates!VendorID <> lngCurrentVendorID Then
        HandleMessages "Row Rejected -- Override Labor Rate is not  valid for this vendor"
        ValidateOverride = 0
    End If
End If
rstOverrideLaborRates.Close
Set rstOverrideLaborRates = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: LINQ to SQL and the Entity Framework both work with SQL Server, and Microsoft has been putting more weight behind EF than LINQ to SQL recently. It sounds like you could do with a book on LINQ, basically...

Comment: OK, I won't prefix my titles like that. I'm more used to forumns that don't have tags. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u sure u want to rewrite your program? What else does it beside parsing the excel? I would recommend u into using [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services), i've writen some import/export routines and a conversion using SSIS, it's **extreme** fast and they are [improving it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/12/ssis-what-s-new-in-sql-server-denali.aspx) even more. It's really really good!

I don't think u need, but if u have the need for a GUI u can use start up SSIS package and be notified what's happening in the process.

PS: Logging is implemented out of the box

Comment: I tiptoed into SSIS. I ran into issues. Authentication was sometimes a problem (the Excel workbook is in SP....) Then, I was able (I don't remember how) to actually read the .xlsx, but got column errors I couldn't work through. Remember, some of the columns "appear" to be numeric, but aren't, and vice-versa. Excel being a very weakly-typed system makes assumptions and passes variables accordingly. Am I giving up too easily?

Comment: Yup, u gave up too easily. Within the Excel connection manager u can configure all columns as strings and convert the values later. Btw i'm using EF dbcontext myself alot but for this scenario i would choose SSIS. Maybe ask this question in another form with a SSIS tag?

Answer (score 1):

Use entity framework, the latest patches has made it viable.
I use nhibernate because that's more common where I work.
If the question would have come up a year or two ago, I'd not recommend entity framework but now days it's a viable option.
It's really subjective, chose what you believe will do it for you and try it out, it's not more than that to it really.

Comment: I found this: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff191186.aspx, which I'm watching. So far, I can create the framework. Now, can I use ("consume") it....stay tuned...